# how to manage gesture navigation programmatically using flutter in android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation, android-10.0

So with the new gesture navigation, I was wondering if there were any methods or a package which handled these gestures in flutter. For example, the bottom swipe which directs the user to the home screen or when you hold it, it shows all the running apps, how can I manage those events?

EDIT: There is a Gesture Exclusion API available for android, can we work around that for a Flutter solution to handle gesture navigation?